# How to count for collisions in hmac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, hashmap, hmac

I want to know what is the best way to search for collisions in hmac list and its count. I've tried to find the solution in the Internet. There are some suggestion which is to use dictionary: the key is the hash, the value is how many times it appears. But there seem to be a problem since bytearray and bytes are unhashable type, so they can't be used as dict KEY, cast to str. The suggestion is to create a while loop that searching in list: if the digest isn't in the dict, insert (digest_hmac_dict[hash_value] = 1) else increase the value (digest_hmac_dict[hash_value] += 1). In this way at the end of this loop you will have a dict that you can sort by value (descending order). From there, you can count the collision (i.e. generate one row of the file). Is there any other ways that u can search for collisions in hmac list and its count?

Comment: *...bytearray and bytes are unhashable type...* That is incorrect, only `bytearray` is not hashable. A `bytes` object, being an immutable type, is hashable and may be used as a key.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that you get a collision when used with a cryptographically secure hash function. Judging by your previous question Adler32 is not such a hash function. It's a checksum algorithm which is easily forgeable.